# Celery SQS Broker not receiving event on task

Tags: python, celery, amazon-sqs, celery-task

We want to use celery for listening sqs queue and process event into task

This is the celeryconfig.py file

```
from kombu import (
    Exchange,
    Queue
)


broker_transport = 'sqs'
broker_transport_options = {'region': 'us-east-1'}
worker_concurrency = 10

accept_content = ['application/json']
result_serializer = 'json'
content_encoding = 'utf-8'
task_serializer = 'json'

worker_enable_remote_control = False
worker_send_task_events = True
result_backend = None

task_queues = (
    Queue('re.fifo', exchange=Exchange('consume', type='direct'), routing_key='consume'),
)

task_routes = {'consume': {'queue': 're.fifo'}}
```

And this is celery.py file

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from celery import Celery

app = Celery(__name__)

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@app.task(routing_key='consume', name="consume", bind=True, acks_late=True, ignore_result=True)
def consume(self, msg):
    print('Message received')
    logger.info('Message received')
    # DO SOMETHING WITH THE RECEIVED MESSAGE
    # print('this is the new message', msg)
    return True
```

We are pushing event on sqs using aws cli

```
aws --endpoint-url http://localhost:9324 sqs send-message --queue-url http://localhost:9324/queue/re.fifo --message-group-id owais --message-deduplication-id test18 --message-body {\"test\":\"test\"}
```

we are receiving event on celery worker but our consume task is not calling we want to call it

[image]

How can we call consume task on event coming from SQS, any help would be appreciated

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/routing.html#how-the-queues-are-defined) "The non-AMQP backends like Redis or SQS don’t support exchanges, so they require the exchange to have the same name as the queue. Using this design ensures it will work for them as well."

Answer (score 0):

The message you pushed to SQS using `aws` won't be recognized by the celery worker. You need to call `consume.delay(msg)` to push messages SQS, then your worker will be able to recognize it.